# firebase admin: when validating phone number "An internal error has occurred. Raw server response"

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm creating new user using firebase admin. This user have phone number.
When I fill the phonenumber like this "7777777"
my firebase admin response with proper error:

```
{ 
 Error: The phone number must be a non-empty E.164 standard compliant identifier string.
at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] 
 ...
 ...
errorInfo:
 { code: 'auth/invalid-phone-number',
   message: 'The phone number must be a non-empty E.164 standard 
   compliant identifier string.' 
 },
codePrefix: 'auth' }
```

But if I fill number like this "+7777777" 
my firebase admin response with:

```
{ Error: An internal error has occurred. Raw server response: 
"{"error":{"code":400,"message":"INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER : TOO_SHORT","errors":
[{"message":"INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER : TOO_SHORT","domain":"global","reason":"invalid"}]}}"
at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] ...
errorInfo:
 { code: 'auth/internal-error',
   message: 'An internal error has occurred. Raw server response: 
     "{"error":{"code":400,"message":"INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER : 
     TOO_SHORT","errors":
     [{"message":"INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER : 
     TOO_SHORT","domain":"global","reason":"invalid"}]}}"' 
 },
codePrefix: 'auth' }
```

Why I have this internal error? And how to avoid it?

UPDATE:
I understand about lack of country code. The question is. Why it is Internal error? And not "ordinary" error? What is the difference between these 2 errors.

Answer (score 10):

When you pass moile no to firebase you need to prepend your country code number before mobile no.

Ex :

If your country is US (Country code : +1) and your phone no is 222-333-4444 then you need to send +12223334444

You can also use US test number to test firebase mobile auth

Below is test number and sms code of US 
phoneNumber : "+16505554567"
smsCode : "123456"

Please read full details at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth

Comment: I understand about country code. The question is. Why it is Internal error? And not "ordinary" error? What is the difference between these 2 errors.

Comment: I'm able to send formatted phone number without any problems `phoneNumber: '+1 307 307-3007'`

Answer (score 0):

I've had some odd errors from the firebase system. In my case I'm using Google Sheets as our data store.  Somebody copied and pasted phone numbers from an alternate location into the Google sheet.  Total fail on Firebase.

The phone number looked normal, but we're thinking there may have been some odd character encoding going on.  When we deleted the phone number entry and entered the number manually everything worked fine.

Our specific error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: An internal error has occurred. Raw server response: "{"error":{"code":400,"message":"INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER : Invalid format.","errors":[{
"message":"INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER : Invalid format.","domain":"global","reason":"invalid"}]}}"
```