# I tried making a callable function for createUser but I am getting an error wen I run it and I can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make a user management page and I set up a callable function to run on my web app on firebase to create a new user.  The html function is designed to update users or create new ones.  I am trying to test saving a new user.  As far as I can tell, all the variables match up, but it still receives an error.  The error isn't helpful, so I can't tell what's wrong.  Can someone help?

userManagement.html

```
            function save(){
                if(document.getElementById("password").value === document.getElementById("p2").value){
                    if(document.getElementById("username").value === ""){
                        const createUser = firebase.functions().httpsCallable("createUser");
                        createUser({ email: document.getElementById("email").value, name:  document.getElementById("first").value + ' ' + document.getElementById("last").value, phone: document.getElementById("phone").value, password: document.getElementById("password").value})
                        .then((result) => {
                            // Read result of the Cloud Function.
                            console.log(result.data)
                        });
                    }
                    else{
                    const updateUser = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('updateUser');
                        // Passing params to data object in Cloud functinon
                        updateUser({ email: document.getElementById("email").value, name:  document.getElementById("first").value + ' ' + document.getElementById("last").value, phone: document.getElementById("phone").value, uid: document.getElementById("username").value})
                        .then((result) => {
                            // Read result of the Cloud Function.
                            console.log(result.data)
                        });
                        if(!(document.getElementById("password").value === "")){
                            const updatePassword = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('updatePassword');
                            // Passing params to data object in Cloud functinon
                            updatePassword({password: document.getElementById("password").value, uid: document.getElementById("username").value})
                            .then((result) => {
                                // Read result of the Cloud Function.
                                console.log(result.data)
                            });
                        }
                    }

                }
                else{
                    alert("password and confirm do not match")
                }
            }
```

index.js

```
  export const createUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const {email, name, phone, password} = data;
    await admin
    .auth()
    .createUser({
      email: email,
      displayName: name,
      phoneNumber: phone,
      password: password,
      emailVerified: true,
      disabled: false,
    }).then((result) => {
           // Read result of the Cloud Function.
           console.log(result.data)
    }).catch(console.error);
    return {data: `User updated`}
  });
```

the imports for the pages are:

```
        <script src="/__/firebase/8.7.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebase/8.7.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebase/8.7.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebase/8.7.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebase/8.7.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
        <script src="/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true"></script>
```

and

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
```

Current errors:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would probably help if you also show the full text of the error that you get.

Comment: You will see an `internal` error code whenever there is a server-side error that hasn't been thrown as a [`HttpsError`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.httpserror) ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors)). You'll need to look at your [`createUser` Cloud Function Logs](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/functions/logs?search=&severity=DEBUG) for more information about the error. If I had to guess, I'd say you haven't called `admin.initializeApp()` prior to calling `admin.auth()` in your code.

Comment: Also, you need to secure your calls to `updatePassword` and `updateUser`, in their current form anyone can call those functions. For example, as long as I knew the user ID of an individual, I'd be able to change their password using `updatePassword({ password: "newPassword", uid: "theirUid" })`, then login and take over their account. See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors) on how to check if a user is authenticated and then make sure it's that user (or someone with sufficient priveleges) who is doing the update.

Comment: Prone to `Phone number must be a non-empty E.164 standard compliant identifier string.` as well. I'd recommend checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51231138/firebase-admin-when-validating-phone-number-an-internal-error-has-occurred-ra/51231235) for that.

Answer (score 1):

Someone helped me.  I forgot to initialize admin sdk.